# how to delete image/ images from excel file using PHPExcel?

Tags: php, excel-2007, phpexcel

Can anybody help to solve this issue, i am new for PHPExcel Libraries, 
I want to delete image which is on excel file using PHPExcel.
I did some code here but i am getting error of

> Notice: main(): ArrayIterator::next(): Array was modified outside object and internal position

```
<?php
    require_once '../Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
    require_once '../Classes/PHPExcel.php';        
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load(files/test.xlsx);
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(1);           
    $objPHPExcel = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(1)->getDrawingCollection();
    foreach ($objPHPExcel as $key => $drawing){
        $objPHPExcel->offsetUnset($key);
    }
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
    $objReader->save('excel-files/new_test.xlsx');
?>
```

Comment: `$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load(files/test.xlsx);` loads a spreadsheet file as a PHPExcel object, and assigns it to a variable called __$objPHPExcel__.... `$objPHPExcel = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(1)->getDrawingCollection();` gets an array list of images from the loaded spreadsheet file, and assigns that array to a variable called __$objPHPExcel__.... do you spot the problem so far?

Comment: Sir, Thank you for reply me, using getDrawingCollection(); method gets list of array and assign this array to $objPHPExcel variable. i am clear with this line, after that i am stuck , how to unset images

Comment: DON'T OVERWRITE VARIABLES WITHOUT KNOWING WHAT YOU'RE DOING!!!

Comment: Sorry Sir, Means you said to change the object ($objPHPExcel) name in foreach loop $objPHPExcel->offsetUnset($key); ?  please give the correct code for deleting / removing images from spreadsheet file.

Comment: $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
  $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load('files/test.xlsx');
  $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(1);
    
  $objPHPExcel1 = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(1)->getDrawingCollection();
        foreach ($objPHPExcel1 as $key => $drawing){
   
   $objPHPExcel1->offsetUnset($key);
  }
  $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel,'Excel2007');
  $objWriter->save('excel-files/new_test.xlsx');